# static files are not collected in root folder named as assets

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-settings

***GitHub Repo for all the files related to this question:- [click here](https://github.com/Avengetron/Django-project)***

***UPDATE***
***static files are not being collected in STATIC_ROOT folder***

I have changed settings of the **base directory(telusko)** of my Django framework and also added `{%load static%}` in `index.html` but then also the console of chrome shows:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css
  net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

code snippet of `setting.py`;
`sitetravello` contains all the HTML, CSS, js files and I have created assets for all the static file through cmd `python manage.py collectstatic`.

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILILE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sitetravello')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

The main `index.html` file code is:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Travello</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Travello template project">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link href="{% static 'plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

ERROR IN CHROME:

```
Failed to load resource: the server response with the status of 404(not found)
```

ERROR IN CHROME CONSOLE:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css
  net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: We would need to see your directory structure to help you further. These kind of errors are usually caused by configuring a wrong/different folder for static files...

Comment: all files are located here:- https://github.com/Avengetron/Django-project .......@Daniel @Ralf and I have figure out something that my custom statics files are not being collected in assets folder don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Your `STATIC_ROOT` is set to look for folder(s) named `assets`. Make sure you have your `plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css` inside `assets` named folder.

Comment: sir, that's the issue the statics files are not being collected properly in assets file

Comment: @YashDubey When you run management command `collectstatic`, the contents of the `static` directory in your apps are collected in the directories mentioned in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. I also noticed that you may have a typo `STATICFILILE_DIRS`. You can look at [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs)

Comment: Nothing happen after that typo correction my custom static files are not collected into ```assets```

Comment: It looks like you do have it [here](https://github.com/Avengetron/Django-project/blob/master/telusko/assets/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css) and its the right place as per your setup. I've cloned your project and found that `plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css` does load in the browser from the static. Try clearing your cache if you can't see it in the browser and restarting your server